# IOrderedEnumerable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'WithPrevious'

Tags: c#, linq

I've taken over development of an internal tool, written using C# and WPF.
The code hasn't been updated for some time, so the first task has been to update .NET to 4.7.2 and then upgrade all the associated nuGet packages. After doing so, I had a log of issues where methods and extensions had been deprecated and since removed (it had been at least 3 years since any development work has been done), and I'm struggling with one block of code on how to fix it.
This is the first part of the code, and it has a couple of issues:

```
public IAllocation Interpolate(
    IEnumerable<IPeriodAllocation> periodAllocations,
    IEnumerable<ISeriesReturns> seriesReturns)
{
    var maxPeriod = seriesReturns.Select(sr => sr.Periods).Min();
    var periodAllocationsList = periodAllocations.ToReadOnlyList();
    var last = periodAllocationsList.Last();
    var results = new Allocation(periodAllocationsList
        .OrderBy(pa => pa.Period)
        .WithPrevious()
        .Where(o => o.HasPrevious)
        .Select(o => new
        {
            FromPeriod = o.Previous.Period,
            ToPeriod = o.Current.Period,
            Allocation = o.Previous,
        })
        .With(new
        {
            FromPeriod = last.Period,
            ToPeriod = maxPeriod,
            Allocation = last
        })
        .SelectMany(o => EnumerableEx
            .FromTo(o.FromPeriod, o.ToPeriod)
            .Select(p => new PeriodAllocation(
                p,
                o.Allocation.SeriesAllocations)))
        .ToList());
    ...
}
```

I'm getting an error on lines 6 (`periodAllocations.ToReadOnlyList()`).

By fixing line 6 to `periodAllocations.ToList().AsReadOnly()`, but that then causes line 10 (`.WithPrevious()`).
The error returned from line 10 is:

> 'IOrderedEnumerable' does not contain a definition
> for 'WithPrevious' and no accessible extension method 'WithPrevious'
> accepting a first argument of type
> 'IOrderedEnumerable' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I can't find anything via Google relating to WithPrevious to help get me on the right track.

Comment: Does it work *without* updating it to 4.7.2? If so, load the solution in the working state and you should be able to find where WithPrevious comes from.

Comment: Make another checkout of the project and keep as a reference when doing this. It helps a lot to quickly be able to check the original solution when you are doing large updates such as this.

Comment: I had created a branch before making these changes, so yes, I have the working code available. WithPrevious is an extension of IEnumerable<CurrentAndPrevious<IPeriodAllocation>> IEnumerable<IPeriodAllocation>.WithPrevious<IPeriodAllocation>()    
Returns a sequence of elements representing the current and previous elements of the original sequence.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it works with the .NET upgraded to 4.7.2, as that has been done in a previous iteration. The issue has come about after updating several packages (SimpleInjector, Caliburn.Micro, Caliburn.Micro.Core, Documentformat.OpenXml and SharpVectors, plus a couple of internal packages). So it's something to do with these updates that has caused the issue - I may just need to start again and figure out which package breaks it.

Comment: As I said before: go back to the last version that *does* work, and use that to find out where `WithPrevious` comes from. (Visual Studio should make that easy to find.)

Comment: @JonSkeet see my comment above: WithPrevious is an extension of IEnumerable<CurrentAndPrevious<IPeriodAllocation>> IEnumerable<IPeriodAllocation>.WithPrevious<IPeriodAllocation>() Returns a sequence of elements representing the current and previous elements of the original sequence.

Comment: Yes, I would have guessed it's an extension method - but the important part is where it comes from. We can't tell that, but you should be able to - aside from anything else, by going to the working code, putting the cursor on WithPrevious and pressing F12.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, I had forgotten about using F12! It seems it's part of an internal package that is also broken, so I'll need to contact someone internally to see how to fix it.